# Нужен совет по реализации таймера

Tags: mysql

Вобщем есть скриптик на PHP&MySQL, нужно реализовать такую функцию:
Человек заходит на сайт и хочет пополнить баланс на сайте, я ему выдаю номер кошелька для пополнения и 2 часа времени на пополнение, но если он не пополнит в течении 2х часов как сделать чтоб заявка в БД принимала статус неактивной, ну и вообще как сделать какието манипуляции в БД по истечении какого*то времени

Comment: возможно вам подойдет cron - это дает возможность запускать скрипт в конкретное время или через конкретный промежуток времени...

Comment: А зачем вам делать в БД какие то манипуляции по истечении времени ? Пишите в запись сразу время окончания действия. Все записи по которым не поступили деньги и дата истечения меньше текущей автоматом _считаются_ неактивными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте новое поле create_time (тип INT) в таблице заявок и указывайте там значение time() при создании заявки. При выборке данных проверяйте текущий time() с сохраненным значением в базе. Если (time() - create_time)/3600 > 2 , то заявка не активна.

Другой вариант - создать поле deadline_time и записывать там время на 2 часа позже текущего. time() + 2*3600. Далее проверять поле с текущим time()